# What's the name of the Makefile 'match' special variable?

Tags: variables, makefile, pattern-matching

What is the name of the special Makefile variable that contains the match of `%`, to use in the rule body?

As an example, I would like to use it like this:

```
%.o: %.c
             @echo Matched $MATCH
             $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

where I put `$MATCH` there because I can't remember the actual name of that special pattern-match variable.

In other words, if the user says `make foo.c` I want to output `Matched foo`.

I didn't find it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Special-Variables.html), but I it exists because I've used it before ...

Answer (score 3):

From the [GNU Make software manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), the special variable you are referring to is `$*`, the implicit stem match:

> The stem with which an implicit rule matches (see How Patterns Match).
>   If the target is `dir/a.foo.b` and the target pattern is `a.%.b` then the stem is `dir/foo`.
>   The stem is useful for **constructing names of related files**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a specific variable, but here is a solution for you:

```
%.o: %.c
    @echo Matched `basename $@ .o`
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```